# SQL Server multi tenant database partitions vs indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, multi-tenant, database-partitioning, database-indexes

I have a OLAP Database on SQL Server following a Star schema.
I have several fact tables and several dimensions tables.
The facts have between 30 millions and 150 millions of rows. But I am in a multitenant context (I have the tenant id in every fact).

The goal is to have good performances for queries on the fact tables. They are linked to 6-7 dimensions and the queries can have 1,2 ... 10 filters.
But all the queries have a where clause on the tenant id.

I was wondering if the best solution was to partition my fact tables with the first letter of the tenant id for example. Or if the best is to make several indexes (but my queries can filter on 10 fields including multiple joins so I have a lot of indexes if I want to cover efficiently all queries).

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Assuming your queries are not going to span across different tenants, it would be good idea to partition your fact table based on tenantid, such that each tenant will have it's own partition of fact tabl.e

Comment: Thank you for your advise. 
But on SQL Server i can't partition on a field, i have to do a function. 
That's why I was wondering if i could partition of the first letter (or the two firsts).

Comment: How many tenants do you have?  I'm not sure if partitioning is really needed for this problem.  Just having `tenant_id` as the first column in the relevant indexes might be sufficient.

Comment: I have around 500 tenants.
The problem is that I have a lot of possible combinations in my queries. I have 9 filters possible, and you can choose those who want (and some made a join with a dimension table).